# Ayuda con FileSystemWatcher y FileCopy

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un watcher para hacer que cada que se manda un archivo a una carpeta compartida de la cual tengo permisos de lectura y escritura, para resumirlo tengo permisos de administrador.

Lo que quiero lograr es que cada que se mande un archivo a esa carpeta, copiar este archivo a una carpeta en mi computadora "Localmente" y despues de tener esta copia eliminar el archivo que esta en la carpeta compartida, estuve viendo unos metodos y los use y todo funcionaba bien pero despues me pidieron poder cambiar la direccion de la carpeta de destino y la carpeta de origen del archivo, a la hora de estar en el test de esta parte cuando cambio la carpeta de destino o de origen todo bien pero si cambio las 2 me dice lo siguiente:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path '\MXD6C4Y7M2\Users\dmontane\Desktop\test2\paco.xml' is denied.'

Este error a veces ocurre con el File.Copy o con el File.Delete y el error es mio por que el watcher siento yo esta mal implementado por favor ayuda este es el codigo:

El valor del pathr es la carpeta externa y el valor de path2 es la carpeta interna y si despues de hacer la copia se manda borrar pero no se como hacerle para que haga pregunte si la copia fue satisfactoria y luego borrarlo.

```
 [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public static void Run()
        {
            string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            FileSystemWatcher watcher2 = new FileSystemWatcher();
            try
            {
                watcher.Path = pathr;
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                watcher.Filter = "*.xml*";
                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error "+e.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                watcher2.Path = path2;
                watcher2.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                watcher2.Filter = "*.xml*";
                watcher2.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(LocalChange);
                watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + e.Message);
            }

        }
// -----------------------------------------Define the event handlers---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
                              //especifica que se hace cuando un archivo se cambia crea o se borra
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            sourceFile = Path.Combine(pathr, fileName);
            destFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path2))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
            }
            try
            {
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {

            }
            cambio = true;    
        }
        private static void LocalChange(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //especifica que se hace cuando un archivo se cambia crea o se borra
            sourceFile = Path.Combine(pathr, fileName);
            destFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName);
            if (File.Exists(sourceFile))
            {

                try
                {
                    File.Delete(sourceFile);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }
            cambio = true;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Tienes permiso de acceso a  '\MXD6C4Y7M2\Users\dmontane\Desktop\test2\paco.xml', porque el mensaje habla de acceso no autorizado?

Comment: si si tengo igual ya lo solucione utilizando un metodo en el cual esperaba a que el archivo dejara de ser leeido y luego ya procedia

Comment: Comenta tus soluciones, que les pueden servir a otros. Gracias.